# Apache 403 forbidden symlink

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I have a symlink from /home/public/folder to /var/www/example.com/thing but when I try to access example.com/thing i get 403 forbidden.
 I have given /home, /home/public and /home/public/folder o+x permissions.
 I have this line at the bottom of my apache config file:
`Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`
but I still get this error. What can I do?